# Entity Framework joins 3 tables when one of the models has ICollection list

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I would like to join 3 models but one of them has ICollection and I dont know how to manage with this. I wrote simple SQL and it works but I dont know how to perform it in code c# using linq. My models.

```
public class Car
{
    public int IDCar { get; set; }
    public virtual CarProducent Producent { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public double Engine { get; set; }
    public int HorsePower { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
}

public class CarProducent
{
    public int IDCarProducent { get; set; }
    public string producent { get; set; }
}
public class Klient
{
    public int IDKlient { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars{ get; set; }
}
```

I would like to join this 3 models to receive full detail about it. I wrote that kind of query

```
var car = (  from cars in dataContext.Cars
             join prod in dataContext.CarProducent on cars.Producent.IDCarProducent equals prod.IDCarProducent
             join client in dataContext.Clients on cars.IDCar equals client.Cars. /*Here I don't know how to join */
             where cars.IDCar == id
             select new
             {
                 cars.IDCar,
                 cars.Model,
                 cars.Engine,
                 cars.HorsePower,
                 cars.ProductionDate,
                 prod.producent,
                 client.name,
                 client.surname,
                 client.address,
                 client.phone
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am just learning so any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply

```
from client in dataContext.Klient
from car in client.Cars
where cars.IDCar == id
select new
{
  car.IDCar,
  car.Model,
  car.Engine,
  car.HorsePower,
  car.ProductionDate,
  car.Producent.producent,
  client.name,
  client.surname,
  client.address,
  client.phone
}
```

If you add another Navigation property you could also write

```
from car in dataContext.Cars
where cars.IDCar == id
select new
{
  car.IDCar,
  car.Model,
  car.Engine,
  car.HorsePower,
  car.ProductionDate,
  car.Producent.producent,
  car.Client.name,
  car.Client.surname,
  car.Client.address,
  car.Client.phone
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, I even didn't expect I can do this way, everything works properly. :)